# How to display value on a card/panel

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I want to return the string query in the HomeController as value from my api (asp.net core) to display in my angular card/panel. My grid is loading correctly but my card/panel is not. My problem is how to declare a varable to hold and return the value in the HomeController.

**OrderDetail table**

| Item | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 3.00 | 80 |
| Pie | 2.00 | 20 |
| Pork | 5.00 | 32 |

[image]

HomeController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public object Get()
{
    string query = "Select Sum(OrderDetail.Quantity) as TotalQuantity from OrderDetail";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    SqlDataReader dr;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(dr);
            dr.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    return new JsonResult(dt);
}
```

component.ts

```
  public data:object[];  
  public totalQuantity;
  
  constructor(private service: TestService) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();    
  }

  getData(): void {
   this.service.get().subscribe(data => {
   this.data = data;
   this.totalQuantity = data;
  });
}
```

html

```html
<ng-template #content>
  <div class="card">          
    <div class="card-content text">Total Quantity</div>
    <div class="card-content number">{{ totalQuantity }}</div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

service.ts

```
export class TestService {
  get(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('api/CountAPI');
  }
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);
      console.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
      return (result as any);
    };
  }
}
```

Expected output/result

[image: expected result]

Comment: You are acceding to an Object, you can see the entire Object using JSON.stringify(noOfCustomer ), and then you access to any properties you want

Comment: Can you elaborate on this more in order to understand your suggestion?

Comment: You are sending an object to your front, maybe like this {"customer: "Jhon", "noOfCustomer": "132"}, then you print in your hmtl the entired object, you need to print the especific property, you can access to them like this:  <div class="card-content number">{{ TheNameObject.noOfCustomer }}</div> . Can you show your me the content of noOfCustomer ?

Comment: @alonso I have modified my question

Comment: Where you set `this.totalQuantity = data` you need to see what the types are on this object. I see you are either not using types or just setting `any` which defeats the entire purpose of TypeScript. If you had a strongly typed object here it would be easy to see what this object has on it. Now you need to either just know what it is or place a `debugger` or `console.log(data)` to see what properties that object has

Comment: @Chris, when l set this.totalQuantity = data.length in another controller it returns total row count successfully, but my main issue is how to declare a variable in the HomeController to return the value.

Comment: Like I said, I depends what `data` has here. We don't have access to your application so the only one who can answer that is you. Either debug or log the value of `data` so you can see what properties are on hat object when you receive it. I **highly** recommend you make some types instead of using `any` as that would have already solved the mystery for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just define an action to return a string value

```
        [HttpGet]
        public string test()
        {
            return "mystring";
        }
```

javascript

```
<script>
    fetch('https://localhost:7062/test', {      
  method: 'GET'
})
.then(function(body){
  return body.text(); 
})
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);})     //the data is a string now
</script>
```

[image]